# How to prevent the array out of range?

Tags: c#

Here I have some code. How to prevent it **out of range** when keep increase and loop for another file name?

```
int deleteIndex = 0;

FileSystemInfo[] fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(basepath)
  .GetFileSystemInfos()
  .OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime)
  .ToArray();

while (fileInfo[deleteIndex].Name.StartsWith("GDZ"))
{
    deleteIndex++;

    //if index out of range, cancel delete folder
    if (fileInfo.Count() <= deleteIndex) 
        return;
}
```

Comment: Check if `fileInfo.Length > 0` before doing while.

Comment: Try `while(deleteIndex < fileInfo.Length && fileInfo[deleteIndex].Name.StartsWith("GDZ"))`

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (deleteIndex<fileInfo .Length)
```

Answer (score -1):

when `fileInfo` is empty `fileInfo[0]` will throw the exception. The code below will do the trick;

```
while (fileInfo.Length > 0 && fileInfo[deleteIndex].Name.StartsWith("GDZ"))
        {
            deleteIndex++;

            //if index out of range, cancel delete folder
            if (fileInfo.Count() <= deleteIndex) 
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I'd love to hear the reason for the downvote. Thank you.